# Optimal Colmin(s) for multidmensional arrays in R

Tags: r

I am trying to mimick the `colMeans`function with other functions: `min`, `max`, `var`, `quantile`, such as:

```
colMin <- function(x, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) {
  apply(x,
        MARGIN = (dims + 1):length(dim(x)),
        FUN = min,
        na.rm = na.rm)
}

rowMin <-
  function(x, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) {
    apply(
      x,
      MARGIN = 1:dims,
      FUN = min,
      na.rm = na.rm
    )
  }
```

This is slow, and I have seen different implementation with fast processing in 2D such as in `rfast`or `matrixStats`.

Is there a good approach you would advise?

Thank you!

### Edits

- Function was corrected for inversion of indices

Answer (score 1):

For 2D arrays, probably you can try `pmin` + `asplit`, e.g.,

```
# colMin
do.call(pmin, c(asplit(x, 1), na.rm = TRUE))


# rowMin
do.call(pmin, c(asplit(x, 2), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: For dimensions > 2, do you suggest coupling this with `apply`?

Comment: @leparc I don't think I have better solutions than `apply`

Answer (score 1):

Could you write something with `Rcpp` for speed?

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
NumericVector  colMin_cpp(DataFrame df, int ncol) {
    NumericVector out_vec(ncol);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ncol; i++){
      NumericVector v = df[i];
      out_vec[i] = min(v);
    }
    
    return out_vec;
}')


colMin_r <- function(x, dims = 1, na.rm = TRUE) {
  apply(x,
        MARGIN = (dims + 1):length(dim(x)),
        FUN = min,
        na.rm = na.rm)
}

df = data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10),
                y = sample(1:100, 10),
                z = sample(1:100, 10))

colMin_cpp(df, ncol(df))
#> 1 1 17
colMin_r(df)
#>  x  y  z 
#>  1  1 17
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: For multidimensional vectors of dim > 2, would you recommend that I code this in C++ or that I couply with `apply`?

Comment: I don't have a solid recommendation, just giving an option.